# ¿Como obtener solamente las categorías, asociadas a un rubro, en una pantalla modal de edición?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Buenas tardes a todos/as, soy nuevo en el manejo de php, javascript y ajax. Actualmente me encuentro en la siguiente situación:
El rubro Varios tiene solamente asociado la categoría Entreverado.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que solamente me muestre la categoría que tiene asociado, en lugar de todas las categorías registradas?.

El inconveniente lo presento concretamente en el
select `name="categoríaEdit"`.

Este es el código:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="rubroEdit">Rubro</label>
          <select name="rubroEdit" class="form-control" id="rubroEdit">
             <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
               <?php 
                   $query2 = $link -> query ("SELECT * FROM rubro");
                   while ($valores1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) { ?>
                 <option value=<?php echo $valores1[0]; ?>><?php echo $valores1[1] ? </option>
                <?php } ?>
           </select>
        </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="categoríaEdit">Categoria</label>
          <select name="categoríaEdit" class="form-control" id="categoríaEdit" required>
            <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
              <p>The time is <span id="time"></span>.</p>
                    <?php 
                    $variable = "<div id=\"demo\">as</div>";
                     echo $variable;
                 $query3 = $link -> query ("SELECT c.id as id,c.descripción as descripción 
                    FROM categoría as c
                   JOIN rubro as r ON r.id = c.RUBRO_id
                   /*WHERE c.RUBRO_id = $idr*/
                   ORDER BY c.descripción ASC");
                   while ($valores2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query3)) { ?>
                 <option value=<?php echo $valores2[0]; ?>><?php echo $valores2[1] ?></option>
        <?php } ?>       
    </select>
  </div>
```

---

```
var r = '';
let enlace = document.querySelectorAll('[data-target="#myModalEdit"]');
enlace.forEach(a => {
  a.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let tds = this.closest('tr').querySelectorAll('td');
    let id = this.dataset.id;

    let url = "articulos/getRubro.php"
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('id', id)

    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData
    }).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
      idEdit.value = data.id
      document.querySelector('#descripciónEdit').value = data.descripción
      document.querySelector('#cantidadEdit').value = data.cantidad
      document.querySelector('#precio_costoEdit').value = data.precio_costo
      document.querySelector('#precio_ventaEdit').value = data.precio_venta
      document.querySelector('#utilidadEdit').value = data.utilidad
      document.querySelector('#rubroEdit').value = data.id_rubro
      document.querySelector('#categoríaEdit').value = data.id_categoría
      let idrubro = document.querySelector('#rubroEdit').value = data.id_rubro
      $.ajax({
        url: 'article.php',
        method: 'GET',
        data: { idrubro, idrubro },
        success: function (respuesta) {
          //console.log(data[6]) Aqui obtengo el id del rubro que necesito
          r = data[6].toString()
        },
        error: function (e) {
        }
      })
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  });
});
```

Adjunto una imagen, ilustrativa de lo mencionado anteriormente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]